# Python requests behaviour from Ruby (convert python code to ruby)

Tags: python, ruby

If I use Python (with requests) as follows:-

```
r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post","Post from Python")
r.text
u'{\n  "args": {}, \n  **"data": "Post from Python"**, \n  "files": {}, \n  **"form": {}**, \n  "headers": {\n    "Accept": "*/*", \n    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", \n    "Connect-Time": "1", \n    "Connection": "close", \n    "Content-Length": "16", \n    "Host": "httpbin.org", \n    "Total-Route-Time": "0", \n    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.3.0 CPython/2.7.8 CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64/1.7.32(0.274/5/3)", \n    "Via": "1.1 vegur", \n    "X-Request-Id": "7e8907d6-b5ad-4715-99e2-eacba921cf7e"\n  }, \n  "json": null, \n  "origin": "92.28.252.59", \n  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"\n}'
```

How do I get the same result from Ruby?  Specifically, I want to know, how to get the "Post from Ruby" into the same field in the response?

For example if I use rest-client, the "Post from Ruby" message winds up in a different field of the response than in the Python case above:

```
RestClient.post("httpbin.org/post","Post from Ruby") 
=> "{\n \"args\": {}, \n \"data\": \"\", \n \"files\": {}, \n \"form\": {\n \"Post from Ruby\": \"\"\n },... (truncated)
```

I have also tried nestful and httpclient and see the same behaviour

Comment: For example if I use rest-client, the "Post from Ruby" message winds up in a different field of the response than in the Python case above:

 RestClient.post("http://httpbin.org/post","Post from Ruby")
=> "{\n  \"args\": {}, \n  \"data\": \"\", \n  \"files\": {}, \n  \"form\": {\n    \"Post from Ruby\": \"\"\n  },... (truncated)

I have also tried nestful and httpclient and see the same behaviour

Comment: Try [typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) or [faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) library as they are easier to use like `requests` in python.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about converting code from one language(python) to another(Ruby).

Comment: @bibstha - Could you post a quick example please?

Comment: @User089247 I have amended the title accordingly

Comment: That is strange. What is 'data'? Usually when it goes to 'form' is the correct behavior isn't it?

Comment: @Crush_157 : I sympathize the situation you have here. But, the question would still be considered as off-topic because you're asking community to write code for you. Please try something of your own and then come back if some piece of code doesn't work, which shows that you did put an effort to solve your problem.

Comment: @Crush_157 : The output from httpbin is strange to me. In a post request, it is usually always form values or arguments. Not sure how requests is sending the data so it appears in the data. Why do you need the value in data anyways? Isn't form the right way to go?

Comment: @User089247 - I would have put all of the examples in line, but having just signed up, I can only have two links (i.e. URLs) in my post, which is a bit of an issue if (by definition) the code and the responses contain URLs.  ;-)

Comment: @Crush_157 : Why you want to put links in post? instead post the code you've tried so far. It allows people to see what went wrong where in your code, and that'd be easier to help you instead of giving answers which may not be even related to your question/problem.

Comment: @bibstha - thank you mate.  I think requests must be setting a default content-type of text/plain:

Drilling into it with curl:

$ curl -X POST -d "Hello from curl" "http://httpbin.org/post" -H "Content-Type: text/plain"
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "Hello from curl",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},

But if I don't set that, I get the data in the form...
$ curl -X POST -d "Hello from curl" "http://httpbin.org/post"
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {
    "Hello from curl": ""
  },

Comment: @User089247 "http://httpbin.org/post" i.e. the target URL is regarded as a link.  And the code so far is commands typed into Python / Ruby / Bash shells (as above).